# complex query to load records from multiple nested records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :watched_videos
  has_and_belongs_to :course
end
```

and a course model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos      
  has_and_belongs_to :users
end
```

and a video model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :watched_videos      
end
```

and my wathed video model look like

```
class WatchedVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video      
end
```

I want all those courses which all videos have been viewed by a user. for example. There are two courses with 2 videos each and user have seen all videos of course one and my query has to return that course. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

First get all users who has watched any video:

```
users = WatchedVideo.pluck('Distinct("user_id")')
```

Fetch all courses which have above users:

```
courses = Course.includes(:videos).where('user_id in (?)', users)
```

Iterate over courses to find course who's all videos are watched:

```
cour = []
courses.each do |c|
 c.users.each do |u|
  cour << c if u.wathced_videos.pluck(:video_id) == c.videos.pluck(:id)
 end
end
```

There is scope for optimization. You can optimize this further